# IIS 7.5 svchost.exe(ftpsvc) 100% cpu

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5

I have a client with a server using IIS 7.5.   They have an FTP service for their customers for use with their software package.

The server has been working flawlessly for years.  Just over the last week the svchost.exe(ftpsvc) process is using 100% cpu.  Until you reboot.  Then it is good for a day or so and happens again.

The ftp site has anonymous connections disabled, and just basic passthrough authentication.  When the server is at 100% I can remote into the server and see in IIS under FTP Current Sessions a few (10 maybe) of their customers hung in a RETR command.  I am not sure if this is what is causing the issue or something else.

If anyone knows the best way to find the root cause of the problem I would appreciate any help you could give.

All windows updates have been installed.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon Brian,

I experimented same behavior.
Can you check if you have KB4338818 installed?
It's seems to be the origin of this behavior.

I found this information here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/08662831-952f-4d86-b8e8-67874f117d98/july-2018-update-kb4338815-and-kb4338824-causes-issues-within-world-wide-web-publishing-service-on?forum=winserver8gen

After uninstall this update (KB4338818) the problem is gone.

Comment: Yes I have that update installed.  It installed on July 11th and I started seeing issues on the 13th so I will do an uninstall and report back with what happens.   Thank you for letting me know.  How did you find the solution?  I have been searching for days.

Comment: I searched "ftpsvc high cpu" in Google with "Past month" filter.